# Create foreach loop from JSON file

Tags: php, json

I have a json file (items.json) that looks like following:

```
{"response":{"success":1,"current_time":1446373851,"items":[
{
"Item1": {"last_updated":1446372015,"quantity":73,"value":1200},
"Item2": {"last_updated":1446372015,"quantity":40,"value":5297},
"Item3": {"last_updated":1446372015,"quantity":148,"value":2507}
}]}}
```

I've tried to create a for loop to create elements with values from each item in the json:

```
$values = file_get_contents( $siteurl.'/json/items.json');
$values = json_decode($values);

foreach ($values->items as $key => $value) {

if($value==Item1 && $value->value>1000){
<p><?php echo $value->value ; ?></p>
}
}
```

In the above example i'm testing the first value in "items" (Item1). I'd like to be able to have a foreach for all these three items.

But the browser outputs the following error "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in".

How do I correctly create a foreach where I can get values from all "items" objects (ex "Item1" and "Item2) that works for my json file format.

Comment: Just var_dump it and check the structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your items are actually within the "response" object, and then you have the items object wrapped in an array as well. If you are unabled to edit items.json then you can do

```
$values = file_get_contents( $siteurl.'/json/items.json');
$values = json_decode($values);

foreach ($values->response->items as $key => $value) {
   foreach($value as $key => $value) {
       if($key == 'Item1' && $value->value > 1000) {
           echo $value->value;
        }
    }
}
```

A better solution however would be to remove the array from items.json (square brackets) as it seems to be redundant and then do:

```
$values = file_get_contents( $siteurl.'/json/items.json');
$values = json_decode($values);

foreach ($values->response->items as $key => $value) {
    if($key == 'Item1' && $value->value > 1000) {
        echo $value->value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this way

```
foreach ($values as $key => $value) {


    foreach($value->items as $k => $v){
        foreach($v as $k1 => $v1){


            echo ($v1->value);
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try below code which is written to provide you exact output according to your requirement.

```
$data = file_get_contents( $siteurl.'/json/items.json');
$values = json_decode($data);

foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
    foreach($value->items as $key1 => $value1){
        foreach($value1 as $key2 => $value2){
            if($key2=="Item1" && $value2->value>1000){
                 echo $value2->value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```